# Is there a kind of map that optimize for *sequences of keys* that have the same value?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

If you are mapping Java shorts to a few immutable objects, and it is often the case that a consecutive sequence of short keys (neighbors) map to the same value,  it there some map structure that allows you to save more memory then a hashmap, while keeping a fast access speed (O(1) or O(log(N)))?

I could inverse the map, and I would use much less memory, but then I would have to go through every mapping to know if a specific short is mapped, and to what it is mapped (O(N)).

I suppose some kind of treemap could do that; maybe there is something like that in some collection library?

Comment: Can you give a better idea of how many keys and values there are?  Is the set of values fixed?

Comment: I will have short as keys, and "short plus optional data" as value. Values 0-255 don't have any "optional data" and can be "merged". *All the keys* need to be mapped, but since an estimated 50% are going to map to "0", I was intending to simply leave those out and default to "0". And while there will be 65K possible values, some of which have "optional data", I expect that 90% at least will be between 1 and 10, without "optional data", and those could be merged. The average length of a sequence of same value will be around 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a binary tree with one entry for each interval of shorts that map to the same value.
The key would be the start of the interval, while the data is the length of the interval plus the mapped objects.

Thus to find if given short is mapped you need to locate the node in the tree, with the highest key less than the given one (O(logn)) and check whether the given one falls within the interval this node represents.

Comment: This fits exactly my problem. For least memory usage, I can implement it as two arrays. One for the sorted keys, and one for the values. I then get O(n) when I change the map, because of arraycopy, but this should happen rarely.

Answer (score 2):

I once used a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a custom key class and corresponding comparator to implement this. My key class contained both ends of a range of `double` values. Queries were specified as a range with both ends being the same and the comparator did the rest.

There were a few choices to be made, though:

- How should `remove()` be handled?
- What should happen if a `get()` is issued with a key range that overlaps two or more ranges?
- Would it make sense to bundle this behaviour in a new Map implementation - possibly a subclass of TreeMap?

Comment: While I can see how this works for querying the tree, I think put and remove will be problematic to implement. In other words, I suspect you don't gain much by extending TreeMap, rather than writing your own implementation based on AbstractMap.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Looking at it in details, this seems too "general". They say: "efficiently retrieve all intervals overlapping another interval or point" I will query only by "point", and there can only ever be a *single* interval that matches. But maybe I misinterpret the details.

Comment: @Sebastien, that doesn't mean you can't use them.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is pretty different - very old-fashioned, but approaching O(1), small and fast.
90% of the values will fit into 4 bits, whereas a map or tree entry takes hundreds of bits to represent (without a lot of custom reimplementation).  So start by representing them in an array of 4-bit entries:

```
// Used to store nybbles containing small values, with direct arithmetic mapping.
// A value of 15 indicates that the value is larger than 14.
// Size: 32KB
byte[] zeroTo14Array = new byte[(1<<Short.SIZE)/2];
static final short BIGGER_THAN_NYBBLE = 15;
```

Then use an efficient short-to-byte map (from [fastutil](http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/) or [gnu trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) to represent the values from 15 to 255:

```
// Use to store bytes with values 15-255.
// If value is 0, value is larger than 255.
Short2ByteOpenHashMap byteMap = new Short2ByteOpenHashMap();
```

Finally, use an efficient short-to-object map for everything else:

```
// Use to store values larger than 255 
Short2ObjectOpenHashMap<Value> objectMap = new Short2ObjectOpenHashMap();

// just a sketch
public class Value
{
    short shortValue;
    String optional;
}
```

I can post the rest of the *untested* code, if you'd like.

Comment: Actually, this was what I had in mind first. Simple and straightforward, but I think the interval/range tree will save me a lot more memory. In the end, I just have to create several implementations, including this one, and run a benchmark to make my choice.

Comment: Write back when you've got results!